# Access DOM element with template reference variables on component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to get a reference to the DOM element for a component in an Angular 2 template using a template reference variable. This works on normal html tags but has a different behaviour on components. e.g.

```
<!--var1 refers to the DOM node -->
<div #var1></div>

<!--var2 refers to the component but I want to get the DOM node -->
<my-comp #var2></my-comp>
```

Is there any way force the template reference variable to refer to the DOM node even if it is on a component? And if so is it covered in the docs anywhere? The only docs I can find on this are here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars and they don't go into much detail on how the variables are resolved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on how you are going to use this reference.

1) There is no straight way to get component DOM reference within template:

```
 import {Directive, Input, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

 @Directive({selector: '[element]', exportAs: 'element'})
 export class NgElementRef implements OnInit
 {
    @Output()
    public elementChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    public elementRef:ElementRef;

    constructor(elementRef:ElementRef)
    {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
        this.elementChange.next(undefined);
    }

    @Input()
    public get element():any
    {
        return this.elementRef.nativeElement;
    }

    public set element(value:any)
    {

    }

    ngOnInit():void
    {
        this.elementChange.next(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<my-comp [(element)]="var2"></my-comp>
<p>{{var2}}</p>
<!--or-->
<my-comp element #var2="element"></my-comp>
<p>{{var2.element}}</p>
```

2) You can get this reference in component that owns template with `@ViewChild('var2', {read: ElementRef})`.

Comment: So 4 years later I googled my own answer on StackOverflow!

Comment: `@ViewChild('var2', { read: ElementRef })` is the way!

Answer (score 4):

As of Angular 8, the following provides access to the ElementRef and native element.

```
/**
 * Export the ElementRef of the selected element for use with template references.
 *
 * @example
 * <button mat-button #button="appElementRef" appElementRef></button>
 */
@Directive({
    selector: '[appElementRef]',
    exportAs: 'appElementRef'
})
export class ElementRefDirective<T> extends ElementRef<T> {
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef<T>) {
        super(elementRef.nativeElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point out the code in Angular repo? Because I don't find it at all. It's not in Angular 8.

Comment: @jsgoupil Sorry for the confusion. I meant that this code works with Angular 8 as far as I've tested. It is not included in Angular.