# Get the ElementRef from the Template reference variable in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-template-variable

In the following code

```
<input #myRef1 />
<input #myRef2 my-custom-attribute />
```

The `#myRef1` will be an `ElementRef`, and `#myRef2` will be `MyCustomAttributeComponent` directive. Basically, it implicitly finds the first component and associates it to the template reference variable.
I can force which directive/component I want thanks to `exportAs`, but here, I actually want the `ElementRef` in both cases.

Is there something to force `#myRef2` to be an `ElementRef` **WITHOUT** the TypeScript `@ViewChild(..., { read: ElementRef })`. I need to access `myRef2` as an `ElementRef` in my template.

Comment: Now it looks like I'm talking to myself, @trevor-karjanis had asked a question in comments here but deleted it. The connected question to this one would be similar but the answer is not as good as quality goes.

Comment: Sorry, I had flagged this as a duplicate, and it automatically commented. I'm not sure why that comment was removed. I intended to post a new answer on the duplicate.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42183472

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inject ElementRef Service in directive, then access injected service reference in template like this

**component.html**

```
<input #ref="custom" type="text" appCustom>
{{ref.template}}
```

**directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[appCustom]',
    exportAs: 'custom'
})
export class CustomDirective {     
         constructor(public template:ElementRef) { }     
}
```

Comment: OMG, this is so ugly, but definitely working. I like! I will keep the answer opened a few days to see if there is any other ways to do it.

Comment: Ok no problem, feel free to share if you find any other solution!

Comment: This is indeed very ugly, surely there must be a better way?

Comment: I think this is actually a rather elegant solution (naming conventions aside)